# Buildozer debug error : "deprecated Gradle features were used in this build"

Tags: python, gradle, kivy, buildozer

I can't seem to get rid of this error while trying to debug my Kivy project. Gradle throws an error, saying

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
> incompatible with Gradle 7.0.

Things I tried:
-running `buildozer clean debug`
-manually deleting my ~/.gradle folder
-downloading a previous version of gradle and placing it inside my ~/.gradle/wrapper/dists

Any ideas on how to solve this? Since all of the buildozer thing is to automate everything into one command, turns out I don't understand much of what's going on under the hood.

(The en of) my output when I run `buildozer debug`:

```
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/urllib3/contrib'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/_securetransport'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/urllib3/packages'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/urllib3/packages/backports'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/urllib3/packages/ssl_match_hostname'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/urllib3/util'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/urllib3-1.26.2.dist-info'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/usr'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/usr/local'...
Listing '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/_python_bundle/_python_bundle/site-packages/usr/local/bin'...
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 30.0.0
[DEBUG]:   -> running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        > Task :compileDebugJavaWithJavac
[DEBUG]:        Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[DEBUG]:        Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[DEBUG]:        Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[DEBUG]:        Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        > Task :transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
[DEBUG]:        /home/vince/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip:/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup: File format not recognized
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        Unable to strip library '1' due to error /home/vince/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip returned from '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup', packaging it as is.
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        > Task :packageDebug FAILED
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:        Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
[DEBUG]:        > org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message)
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        * Try:
[DEBUG]:        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[DEBUG]:        Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[DEBUG]:        See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[DEBUG]:   
[DEBUG]:        BUILD FAILED in 7s
[DEBUG]:        27 actionable tasks: 27 executed

Exception in thread background thread for pid 317137:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sh-1.13.1-py3.8.egg/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew assembleDebug

  STDOUT:

> Task :compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
/home/vince/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip:/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup: File format not recognized

Unable to strip library '1' due to error /home/vince/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip returned from '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/build/intermediates/transforms/mergeJniLibs/debug/0/lib/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup', packaging it as is.

> Task :packageDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed


  STDERR:

[INFO]:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 40):
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.
> org.gradle.tooling.BuildException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 7s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed

[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a && /home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/dists/mempp__armeabi-v7a/gradlew failed!
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name mempp --name Mempp --version 0.1 --package org.test.mempp --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/app --android-entrypoint org.kivy.android.PythonActivity --android-apptheme @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/vinceBot3:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2609,unix/vinceBot3:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2609'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '1.48.2'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '2567'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/vince/Documents/programmes/Mempp'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LOGNAME = 'vince'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_NODE = '/usr/share/code/code'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/vince'
#     USERNAME = 'vince'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     GIT_ASKPASS = '/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass.sh'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '1c12ad7f5ddb478b85688b4cce5cbc58'
#     MANAGERPID = '2322'
#     CHROME_DESKTOP = 'code-url-handler.desktop'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'vince'
#     VSCODE_GIT_IPC_HANDLE = '/run/user/1000/vscode-git-b52e2eb9d1.sock'
#     DISPLAY = ':1'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     VSCODE_GIT_ASKPASS_MAIN = '/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/git/dist/askpass-main.js'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:56813'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/home/vince/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/vince/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/vince/.local/bin:/home/vince/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/vince/.local/bin/:/home/vince/.local/bin/'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '271515'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/usr/share/applications/code.desktop'
#     TERM_PROGRAM = 'vscode'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/vince/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/vince/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/vince/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Nota: My log_level in the spec file is 2.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get through debug by manually deleting the /.buildozer folder along with my buildozer.spec file (not sure if that last one was necessary), and then I ran again `buildozer init` and `buildozer android debug` and it worked! I still get the error:

```
[DEBUG]:    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
[DEBUG]:    Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[DEBUG]:    See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

But it doesn't seem fatal anymore.

Comment: I fiddled a bit more, and I managed to link this error to my (numerous) requirements in my buildozer.spec file. It worked at first after I generated a fresh spec file doing `buildozer init` but then the error came back when I added them back; so I discarded most of them, and after deleting once again my .buildozer folder (didn't find a better way of doing this) it works again.

Comment: and the above error isn't linked to my issue, it's in fact just a warning